# Can an HTML anchor link explicitly require that a secure tab be opened?

Tags: html, anchor, secure-coding

Most browsers have secure tabs (Opera hasPrivate Tabs, Chrome has Incognito Mode, IE has In-Private Browsing, etc.). Anchor tags have the ability to force a link to open in a new tab (`target="_blank"`). **Is there a pure HTML, cross-browser way to force a link to open in a secure tab?**

I don't want discussion about its practicality, security, etc., just whether it's possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The decision to not keep a history and discard cookies must be made by the user.

Comment: Interesting. Why is this? Why not allow the user to do this by clicking an anchor?

Answer (score 1):

is not possible with pure  html, perhaps with a chrome extension